# Truncate seconds and milliseconds in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I'm having a bit of trouble with truncating data. I'm using SQL's GETDATE() function to get the current date and time and enter them into a database. However, I only want to save the date and time up until the minute. In other words, I want dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:00.000 or dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm to be saved when I input new data. How can I go about doing this?

I should note I'm using MS-SQL.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are a number of ways to go about doing this.

For example, you could convert the generated `datetime` from `GetDate()` to a `smalldatetime` first, à la:

```
CAST(GetDate() AS smalldatetime)
```

To be clear, this will round the generated seconds up (or down) to the nearest minute depending up the value of the current second.

**<sub>EDIT:</sub>**

Alternatively, you can have SQL Server truncate a `datetime` for you for a "cleaner" (READ: no rounding, since the value is pre-truncated) conversion to `smalldatetime`:

```
CAST(DateAdd(minute, DateDiff(minute, 0, GetDate()), 0) AS smalldatetime)
```

Answer (score 5):

For truncation:

```
SELECT SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(
         datepart(year  ,dt)
        ,datepart(month ,dt)
        ,datepart(day   ,dt)
        ,datepart(hour  ,dt)
        ,datepart(minute,dt)
      ) 
FROM (SELECT GETDATE()) t(dt)
```

Comment: Just to be noted: this works only from SQL Server 2012 and above.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to convert it to smalldatetime for the assignment (and back as needed).
*smalldatetime* always has seconds and beyond set to 00.

```
SELECT CONVERT(smalldatetime, GETDATE())
```

As this may round up or down, another way to safely *truncate* the seconds would be this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(nchar(16), GETDATE(), 120), 120)
```

The [conversion code 120](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187928.aspx) returns the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss`.

Comment: -1 SELECT CAST('1999-12-31 23:59:30' AS smalldatetime)

Comment: Your selected intermediate conversion format "nchar(16)" is too small, you need at least "nchar(19)" oder seconds would be truncated.

Comment: @AlexanderPowolozki You might want to read a posting before commenting on it. It literally says "another way to safely truncate the seconds". This is the purpose.

Comment: @KekuSemau you are right, i was mentally at my own task, which was to truncate miliseconds but keep seconds. I did not read the posting carefully enought, thank you a lot for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Combine `DATEADD` and `SMALLDATETIME` to truncate

```
CAST(DATEADD(S, -30, dt) AS SMALLDATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other option is not sure why you cannot consider the front-end instead of the back-end so don't change the SQL and thus format in the front-end as dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm or whatever format you need if that is doable or appropriate in the context of what you are trying to achieve. For example in an SSRS report you could format the field in question in the report designer or use the Format function. If it is a webpage or Excel I am sure you could also do something similar.