# Group records by consecutive dates when dates are not exactly consecutive

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, group-by

I have some data that contains dates. I'm trying to group the data by consecutive dates, however, the dates are not exactly consecutive. Here is an example:

```
DateColumn              | Value
------------------------+-------
2017-01-18 01:12:34.107 | 215426 <- batch no. 1
2017-01-18 01:12:34.113 | 215636
2017-01-18 01:12:34.623 | 123516
2017-01-18 01:12:34.633 | 289926
2017-01-18 04:58:42.660 | 259063 <- batch no. 2
2017-01-18 04:58:42.663 | 261830
2017-01-18 04:58:42.893 | 219835
2017-01-18 04:58:42.907 | 250165
2017-01-18 05:18:14.660 | 134253 <- batch no. 3
2017-01-18 05:18:14.663 | 134257
2017-01-18 05:18:14.667 | 134372
2017-01-18 05:18:15.040 | 181679
2017-01-18 05:18:15.043 | 226368
2017-01-18 05:18:15.043 | 227070
```

The data is generated in batches and each row inside a batch takes a few milliseconds to generate. I'm trying to group the results as follows:

```
Date1                   | Date2                   | Count
------------------------+-------------------------+------
2017-01-18 01:12:34.107 | 2017-01-18 01:12:34.633 | 4
2017-01-18 04:58:42.660 | 2017-01-18 04:58:42.907 | 4
2017-01-18 05:18:14.660 | 2017-01-18 05:18:15.043 | 6
```

It is safe to assume that if two consecutive rows are more than 1 minute apart then they belong to a different batch.

I tried solutions involving `ROW_NUMBER` function but they work with consecutive dates (date difference between two rows is fixed). How can I achieve desired result when the difference is fuzzy?

---

Please note that a batch could be much longer than a minute. For example a batch might consist of rows starting from 2017-01-01 00:00:00 and ending at 2017-01-01 00:05:00 consisting of ~3000 rows and each row few dozen or hundred millisecond apart. What is for certain is that batches are at least 1 minute apart.

Comment: re the "is it safe..." we can't say - the business or other domain experts will be the only ones who can say. If in batches you need an identifier for each batch and use that

Comment: do the last two rows in question have the same datetime value or is it a typo?

Comment: @vkp this is weird but not a typo. Perhaps two rows were inserted within 1 millisecond or the actual time got rounded to nearest `datetime` value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
select min(t.dateColumn) date1, max(t.dateColumn) date2, count(*)
from (
    select t.*, sum(val) over (
            order by t.dateColumn
            ) grp
    from (
        select t.*, case 
                when datediff(ms, lag(t.dateColumn, 1, t.dateColumn) over (
                            order by t.dateColumn
                            ), t.dateColumn) > 60000
                    then 1
                else 0
                end val
        from your_table t
        ) t
    ) t
group by grp;
```

Produces:

[image]

uses the analytic function `lag()` to mark starting of next batch based on the difference of `datecolumn` from the last one and then use analytic `sum()` on it to create group of batches and then group by it to find required aggregates.

There may be some misclassification in groups due to rounding issues with `DATETIME`. From [**`MSDN`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx#Anchor_4),

> datetime values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds, as shown in the following table.

[image]

---

Here is the same query rewritten using CTEs:

```
WITH cte1(DateColumn, ValueColumn) AS (
    -- Insert your query that returns a datetime column and any other column
    SELECT
        SomeDate,
        SomeValue
    FROM SomeTable
    WHERE SomeColumn IS NOT NULL
), cte2 AS (
    -- This query adds a column called "val" that contains
    -- 1 when current row date - previous row date > 1 minute
    -- 0 otherwise
    SELECT
        cte1.*,
        CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MS, LAG(DateColumn, 1, DateColumn) OVER (ORDER BY DateColumn), DateColumn) > 60000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS val
    FROM cte1
), cte3 AS (
    -- This query adds a column called "grp" that numbers 
    -- the groups using running sum over the "val" column
    SELECT
        cte2.*,
        SUM(val) OVER (ORDER BY DateColumn) AS grp
    FROM cte2
)
SELECT
    MIN(DateColumn) Date1,
    MAX(DateColumn) Date2,
    COUNT(ValueColumn) [Count]
FROM cte3
GROUP BY grp
```

Comment: Great way to create groups

Comment: Shouldn't it be `datediff( second ...) >60` ?

Comment: Consider `select datediff(mi,'2017-01-18 01:12:20', '2017-01-18 01:13:31'), datediff(second,'2017-01-18 01:12:20', '2017-01-18 01:13:31')` , my understanding is those should be different groups

Comment: Really, `datediff` is on the left and it would be `1>1`  and `71 > 60` , not the same.

Comment: @GurV .. can i now say this logic is a copy of mine :) ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `seconds` and `milliseconds` from `DateColumn` and do the grouping

```
  select min(DateColumn), 
         max(DateColumn), 
         count(*)
  from Yourtable
  group by DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, DateColumn), 0)
```

Here is some questions on truncating seconds for datetime

[Truncate seconds and milliseconds in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496489/truncate-seconds-and-milliseconds-in-sql)

[A way to extract from a DateTime value data without seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896663/a-way-to-extract-from-a-datetime-value-data-without-seconds)

Answer (score -1):

This does not works, if youre comparing gaps between dates (60s). But you can try this, if you need to get records, that belongs to same minute X.

```
SELECT
     [Date1]    =   MIN([DateColumn])
    ,[Date2]    =   MAX([DateColumn])
    ,[Count]    =   COUNT([DateColumn]) 
FROM
    [my_table]
GROUP BY
    DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, [DateColumn]), 0);
```