# SQL Round Seconds on Column to 00 seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server

what's the best way to change seconds and set them 00 on my column
like

2020-07-01 14:15:23.000

2020-07-01 14:15:00.000

I want to round datetime 2020-07-01 14:15:23.000 to 2020-07-01 14:15:00.000

thank you in Advance, I am new to SQL.

Comment: Does the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496489/truncate-seconds-and-milliseconds-in-sql help you?

Comment: The answer suggested by @EdmCoff should work. If it needs to be converted back to the same format again then: select CAST(cast('2020-07-01 14:15:32.888' as smalldatetime) AS datetime)

Comment: @EdmCoff that worked like a treat cheers